# Remote monitoring with screen capture

Tags: nagios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hidden Periodic Screenshots on a corporate workstation?](https://serverfault.com/questions/231387/hidden-periodic-screenshots-on-a-corporate-workstation)

Is there anyway i can perodically take screenshots of a remote computer using nagios? 
I am experimenting with Nagios, and i am trying to explore different monitoring. So my question is apart from using nagios to monitor cpu usage, bandwidth utilization, uptime etc.. can i monitor my worker's productivity by checking what is he doing on his computer in a form of image output. Being able to monitor processes would not be of much help to me, as i only know if he or she is running firefox.exe for example he maybe using excessive use of firefox for facebook or other stuff but he claims he is troubleshooting and looking for solutions on forums.
I saw a check_vnc script but i am unable to install the requsite vnc server anyone succesfully tried the vnc script care to share how to go about it? If not anyother way to try this?

Comment: You'd be better off installing a proxy, or reviewing firewall logs to see what sites people are visitng. This is a pretty ghetto hack...

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible - theoretically yes, however not with out of the box nagios.  You'd have to have a script of some kind sitting on the client machines that can take the screenshot and pass it to nagios.  This seems to me to be an inefficient form of monitoring though.  If you're concerned about the time employees are spending on the internet, employ a proxy server.  You'll know how much time is spent on facebook and other sites versus actual productivity.